# No WiFi after HWE upgrade

Tags: 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

First of all, I'm a complete Ubuntu noob. Without thinking I installed the HWE update and now 14.04 won't detect WiFi

Even Ethernet isn't detected. I am using my phone to write this. Please suggest a remedy.

I was using broadcom wireless driver and now in the additional drivers tab it says This device is not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: Says module wl not found.

Comment: And the other command??

Comment: https://imgur.com/yltrtW5

Comment: In order to install the driver for the wireless, we'll need to identify and fix the ethernet. Please also show us: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jgitKgQ.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44865/discussion-between-chili555-and-silverslash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's get the ethernet going. The *r8169* driver is troubled by auto-negotiation. Let's turn it off and see if it connects:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off
```

Assuming you connect, let's install the wireless driver:

```
 sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Finally, let's make the auto-negotiation permanent:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above the last line exit0, add a new line:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through every step of the process! I was ready to give up on fixing this, install 16.04, and loose most of my data!